# Clone of a rendering in SXA not showing Variant

Tags: sxa

In Sitecore SXA, I've created a clone of a rendering called "Page Content". But when I add this on a page, it doesn't render the data.

When I checked its presentation details I found that the Variant dropdown was blank.

[image]

I also checked in the rendering parameter template and bind it with the necessary base templates.

[image]

Still, it is not filled. Please suggest if anything I need to configure.

Comment: Does your clone have any variants defined for that site?

Comment: Have you checked "Rendering Variants" folder is showing under Presentation in your website?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing variants definitions for your rendering.

To fix it you have to create Rendering Variants folder under your site

`Sites➡>Presentation➡Rendering Variants`

Use your **custom rendering name** as its name just like other RV enabled renderings do and you should see them in rendering parameters dialog.

If it will be something different you can debug it by inspecting following pipeline: `getVariants`.

If you intent is to store variants in your current site then head to: `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.GetVariants.GetSiteVariants`

p.s

Did you use [Clone-Rendering functionality](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/copy-and-customize-a-rendering.html)?

It should automatically create these items for you and even copy variants from source rendering if available globally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create variant in Presentation => variants . Variant name should be same as rendering name (case sensitive, space allow in both) . Once you create variant you need to create variant definition under that . These variant definition will be visible in presentation details of component .